# Limit expression using approximations

Tags: calculus, limits, approximation

I have 2 questions that I'm unsure how to answer, they are both related to same question and function.

I am given a function:

$$f(x)=\ln(\ln(1+\sin^{2}x)+1)+\cos (x) e^{\sin x}-\frac{\ln(x+1)}{e^{x^{2}+x+1}}$$

Q1. Write down the limit expression for the claim that $g(x)=x+1$, is an approximation of $f(x)$ of order $1$ near $0$.

Q2. For the given function $f$ determine if the claim that $g(x)=x+1$, is an approximation of $f(x)$ of order $1$ near $0$ is true. Justify your answer.

Any help on this would be most grateful, as I have no idea what it's getting at or how to answer the above.

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We have that
$$f(x)=\ln(\ln(1+sin^{2}x)+1)+cos(x)e^{sinx}-\frac{ln(x+1)}{e^{x^{2}+x+1}}$$
and so $f(x)\approx f(0)+xf'(0).$ Since 
$$f'(0) = \frac{e-1}{e}$$
and 
$$f(0) = 1$$
we get that 
$$f(x)\approx 1 + x\left(\frac{e-1}{e}\right) = 1+x-x/e.$$

So for question $1$ if $g$ is an approximation of $f$ then it must be that 
$$f(x)\approx f(0) + xf'(0)=1+x $$
and so it must be the case that $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{1+x}=1.$$

For the second question, you can see that since $f'(0)\neq 1$, $g(x)$ is not an approximation of $f$ near $0.$

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much for this.  This has helped me so much and it's so clear.  Thank you.